# Correct terminology for streaming a file into bytes and back

Tags: c#, file, streaming, naming

I have the below methods:

```
    public static byte[] ConvertFileToBytes(string filePath)
    {
        var fInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        var numBytes = fInfo.Length;
        var dLen = Convert.ToDouble(fInfo.Length / 1000000);

        var fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

        var data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
        br.Close();

        fStream.Close();
        fStream.Dispose();

        return data;
    }

    public static void ConvertBytesToFile(byte[] file, string filePath)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream(file);

        var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

        ms.WriteTo(fs);

        ms.Close();
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
    }
```

**What is the correct to name these methods?** (because Convert*XXX*to*YYY* just doesn't cut it in a Utilities library)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) and [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) ;)

Comment: ...haha!  i just continue learning a ton of new things everyday.  Cheers mate!

Comment: Not trying to be a jerk but I have seen this a couple of times. This answer doesn't answer the actual question posed. It is a good suggestion though. The question is about his method signatures not implementation. Would thnk that SO would want to keep these somewhat consistent.

Comment: @Deviant: I think it does in that I'm inferring that the correct names should be "Read" and "Write". Since we're dealing specifically with files, "(de)serialize" is too generic. Same for "marshal", which I think also has slightly different connotations.

Answer (score 2):

The terms usually used are "serialize" and "deserialize" (or sometimes "marshal" and "demarshal").

Comment: To me, both "serialize" and "marshal" imply that you're dealing with some sort of data structure that needs special logic for converting it to bytes - but we already have bytes, they just need to be written to a file (which is nothing but a bunch of bytes as well).

Answer (score 0):

Marshalling/Unmarshalling might be the appropriate term.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)

Comment: hmm, so what's the difference between marshalling and serializing?

Comment: Marshalling is traditionally used when dealing with XML, serializing when dealing with in-memory data structures. Neither really applies to the simple task of writing bytes directly to a file.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ they would be called read and write.

Answer (score 0):

The WriteAllBytes and ReadAllBytes are a good suggestion, but to answer your Question ...

Save() would be a good choice for renaming of ConvertToFile() and Object.CreateFromFile() for the reverse.